# I need help creating a new WPF datagrid for each database table row

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How do I get this query to populate a new wpf datagrid for each row in my database table? I have been researching this for the last 3 days and I cannot find an example that is similar to this. Any advice will help. The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQW6E.png) shows what I am getting it to do currently.

```
public void movieID(BoxOfficeWindow boxWin)
 {
     TextBlock movieId = new TextBlock();
     TextBlock ratingId = new TextBlock();
     DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
     BoxOfficeWindow boxofficewindow = new BoxOfficeWindow();
     connections2 conn = new connections2("mediadatabase", "localhost");
     string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
     string checkTable = "SELECT DISTINCT movie.movieid, movie.ratingtext FROM movie, schedule WHERE(movie.movieid = schedule.movieid AND schedule.systemdate = " + dateTime + ") ORDER BY movie.movieid, movie.ratingtext; ";
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt = conn.ReturnDataTableFromDatabase(checkTable, "schedule");

     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     {
         movieId.Text = dr["movieid"].ToString();
         ratingId.Text = dr["ratingtext"].ToString();
         boxofficewindow.boxGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
         dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
         dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
         boxofficewindow.boxGrid.Children.Add(dataGrid);
         dataGrid = new DataGrid();
     }
     boxofficewindow.Show();
     dt = new DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not do this

```
string checkTable = "SELECT DISTINCT movie.movieid, movie.ratingtext FROM     movie, schedule WHERE(movie.movieid = schedule.movieid AND schedule.systemdate = " + dateTime + ") ORDER BY movie.movieid, movie.ratingtext; ";
```

Look up on how to use AddWithValue to your sql connection query. While the way you have it now is fairly safe, if you ever decide to change the date time to something a user can input data you are making yourself vunerable to SQL injection.

To answer your question you are on the right path. You need to create a new control with code and tell the form where you want it. Right now you're trying to just create new grids without telling the program anything about where its going.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I appreciate it. Yeah, I want to have the datagrid grab the first row and then create another datagrid for the next row and so on. I have tried all that makes sense to me and I am just stumped. when I research this I am having a hard time getting answers that dont talk about winforms datagridview and that is not what I am trying to do here.

Comment: So you want each row in the first image to be in its own grid? How many items should each grid own?

Comment: Only the movieid and rating text in each grid.

Comment: So 2 items. Thanks!

Comment: If each grid only stores one row from your data table each maybe use a different control other than a grid? I think you may be having a hard time with this problem because of the way you are approaching it. It's hard to give more advice without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish but from what it sounds like you should explore different methods.

Comment: Hey Sam, Sorry to bother you again.. So I have it populating with 1 row now instead of all rows but it still wont create another datagrid for the next rows. I know this should be a simple line of code in a certain place but I am closer! Can you take a look and see if you notice something I have missed.

Comment: How do I show you though? It says that it is to many characters and so I cant send the block of code to you.

Comment: It's too hard to tell without seeing everything. If I where to guess from what  I see you are making new data grids on top of each other. Is the grid you see the last row in your data table? You need to tell the program the position of each grid you make.

Comment: Great. Accept answer if it helps :)